# Arc 10 field calculator scripts

Tags: arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I need scripts for the field calculator that:

1. extracts the first word from a column, i.e. "Jones School" - "Jones", and
2. A script that will capitalize this new field, "Jones" - "JONES".

This is Arc 10.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you consider a space as a separator:

Python:

```
!myField!.split(" ")[0].title() # Proper Case
!myField!.split(" ")[0].upper() # Upper Case
```

VBScript:

```
UCase(Left([myField],1)) & LCase(Mid([myField],2,InStr([myField]," ")-1)) ' Proper Case
UCase(Mid([myField],1,InStr([myField]," ")-1)) ' Upper Case
```

Answer (score 5):

The Python string manipulation methods should give you access to all of the features you are looking for:
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

To extract words from a string, take a look at the usage of:

```
str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])
```

For capitalizing your word(s), take a look at the usage of:

```
str.upper()
```